# Ajax error when trying to delete something

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I'm getting the following errors when trying to create a delete option:

```
POST 419 (unknown status)
```

and `AJAX ERROR:  {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

I was wondering what could be wrong with the code? I am new to AJAX and JSON so i'm not really sure where it is going wrong but I have a feeling that a small thing would fix it.

```
$('[data-js-type=modal-submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteCategory",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { id: $("[data-js=open-remove]").find('span').attr('id') },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("Success : ", result);
            if (result.Success) {
                //Reload the Page 
                document.location.reload(true);
            } else if (result.Error) {
                console.log('Error From the Sever ', result.Error);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("AJAX ERROR: ", error);
        }
    });
});

Route::post('/deleteCategory', 'CategoryController@removeCategory')->name('category.delete');

    public function removeCategory(Request $request) {
        //Find the Category 
        $category = Category::findOrFail($request->id);

        //Delete the Category 
        $category->delete();

        //Session Message 
        session()->flash('Success', 'Categorie: ' . $category->name . ' is removed');

        return json_encode(['Success' => 'Categorie: ' . $category->name . ' is 
        removed']);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike GET requests, POST / PUT / DELETE / CREATE requests in laravel require you to pass CSRF token in the request - this is the most popular reason for 419 error:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        ...
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can set it in the headers for all requests instead:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    }
});
```

If this Javascript code is not inside a blade, you can dump it somewhere in your blade, perhaps a `<meta>` tag and access it via jQuery:

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
```

Final option, that I would not recommend is to disable the check for this route in `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`:

```
protected $except = [
    'deleteCateogory'
];
```